# Questions about interior and boundary

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $S\subseteq X$. Do the following two claims hold in Euclidean space and general topological space:

- int($S$) = $S$ \ $\partial(S)$ (I know that int($S$) = $\bar{S}$ \ $\partial(S)$)
- int($S$) \ $\partial(\text{int}(S))$ = int($S$)

Comment: The second equation, as you've written it, is just the statement $\partial (\text{int}(S)) = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Both are true.

$\text{int}$($S$) = $S$ \ $\partial(S)$

Clearly, $\text{int}S\subseteq S\backslash \partial{S}$.

Let $x\in S$ \ $\partial(S)$.
Then $x\in S$ but $x\notin \partial{S}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\notin\overline{S}\backslash\text{int}S$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\in\text{int}S$.

Therefore, $S$ \ $\partial(S)\subseteq\text{int}S$. Hence, $\text{int}$($S$) = $S$ \ $\partial(S)$

---

$\text{int}$($S$) \ $\partial(\text{int}(S))$ =$\text{ int}$($S$).
$\text{int}(\partial(S))=int(\overline{S}\cap \overline{S^c})=\text{int}\overline{S}\cap \text{int}\overline{S^c}=\varnothing$

Answer (score 1):

Both are generally true. For the first, $\operatorname{bdry}S=(\operatorname{cl}S)\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus S)$, so

$$\begin{align*}
S\setminus\operatorname{bdry}S&=S\setminus\big((\operatorname{cl}S)\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus S)\big)\\
&=(S\setminus\operatorname{cl}S)\cup\big(S\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus S)\big)\\
&=\operatorname{int}S\,.
\end{align*}$$

And the second follows from the first: from the first applied to $\operatorname{int}S$ instead of $S$ we have

$$(\operatorname{int}S)\setminus\operatorname{bdry}\operatorname{int}S=\operatorname{int}\operatorname{int}S\,,$$

and of course $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{int}S=\operatorname{int}S$.